# How to turn boost::shared_ptr<> into a reference (&)?

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, reference

So I have a class that uses references (&) with functions like

```
void request(tcp::socket& socket);
```

I am starting migrating all my code to `boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket>` but I would really like to know how to turn my shared_ptrs into references so to be capable to make my code evolve function by function and not in one iteration changing all I have into shared_ptr. So how to turn a shared_ptr into a reference?

Comment: Just remember, if a function just *uses* a reference and does not *store* it, leave it as a reference. There is no improvement in making all a `shared_ptr`, while easier to manage the memory, the semantics are less clear than those of references.

Comment: +1 for that suggesion. References say "I'm not concerned with memory managament, I just use this thing". Taking a `shared_ptr` suggests (incorrectly in this case) "I'm going to keep a copy of that thing, even after I return".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, they're not called links, but references. :)
Second, the `boost::shared_ptr` can just be dereferenced like normal pointer:

```
boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> p(new tcp::socket());
// can be done in two steps (dereference, pass)
tcp::socket& socket_ref = *p;
request(socket_ref);
// or one step
request(*p);
//      ^ -- dereference the shared_ptr
```

Comment: You don't need to call `get`, you can simply do `request(*p)`

Comment: @edA: Ha, you're totally right, thanks. Don't know how that slipped my mind... Editing now.

Answer (score 1):

```
boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> sock;

...

if (sock) request( *sock )
```

I think it's better to rewrite `request()` (if you can) so that it can handle `boost::shared_ptr` or general pointers.

Comment: I respectfully disagree.  A reference argument nicely documents the fact that the parameter is non-null.